# how to map java class having parent class as field with graphql

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I have Java class modeled like:

```java
public class Tree {
    private Integer countLeave;
    private String type;
}
    
public class BananaTree extends Tree {
    private Integer countBanana;
}
    
public class MangoTree extends Tree {
    private Integer countMango;
}
    
public class Forest {
    private List<Tree> trees;
}
```

I want to map above model in GraphQL schema. And have query getForest where it will load all type of tree and return to caller.

```
type Query {
    getForest:Forest
}

interface Tree {
    countLeave:Integer
    type:String
}
    
type BananaTree implements Tree {
    countBanana:Integer
}
    
type MangoTree implements Tree {
    countMango:Integer
}
```

But on doing so getting:
There is no type resolver defined for interface / union 'Tree' type

Comment: Have you had a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251935/graphql-no-resolver-definied-for-interface-union-java